# How do the semicolons work in the for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax

I am writing a function that raises a value to another value without using the exponent operator. I understand the syntax of these kinds of loops as being that initialised values go before the first semicolon, a condition goes between the first and the second semicolon, and after the second semicolon is the looping operations.

I am confused because I think this code should be broken, but it appears to return the correct value. When I put `result *=` base after `count++` inside the parenthesis, then the code does not return the correct value. Why is this?

```js
//Power function
function power(base, exponent) {

  var result = 1
  var count = 0

  for (; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base
  return result;
}

print(power(5, 2));
```

Comment: You just initialized the count variable outside the for loop parentheses. That makes the code work, since it is not required to have a statement in the variable initialization portion, afaik.

Comment: What part exactly seems wrong to you? All three expressions in the `for` loop header (the parenthesized group) are optional. Your code initialized `count` before the loop, which is fine.

Comment: "When I put result *= base after count++ inside the parenthesis, then the code does not return the correct value." - you mean `for (; count < exponent; count++; result *= base)`? "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;". Pretty clear why that does not work.

Comment: You should also put semicolons at the end of each statement. [See here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/semicolons).

Comment: I can't get the points even if I found the answer because people like to close questions. The problem is that you forgot to put {} after your loop statement when you moved result *= base in the for. So the line "return result;" was executed in the loop. You should ALWAYS place {} in your code to avoid that kind of problems when you refactor.

Comment: Oh and it's not a duplicate at all. The other question is about how the semicolon work for the first statement of the for loop, this one is about how to place an operation in the last statement of a for loop...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bkLbaLo9/ for a working example

Comment: Not a duplicate. Linked question is about a semicolon at the beginning of the for, which OPs already understands. The problem here is with the final-expression part of the for.

Comment: Thanks. I realise now that my question was a tad unclear. But the comments were helpful especially Ninjakannon's.

Answer (score 1):

The blank `;` just acts as a placeholder in this case. Because you declared `count = 0` above this `for` loop, this `;` is just there so that declaration isn't overwritten:

```js
var count = 0;
for(/*var count=0*/; count < 4; count++){
  document.write(count);
}
```

**P.S.** I commented out `var count = 0` because that is essentially what the code is representing (because you called that earlier).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you want in javascript. I think the only problem is that you didn't use brackets. This will work.

```js
//Power function
function power(base, exponent){

  var result = 1;
  var count = 0;

  for (; count < exponent; count++, result *= base) {}   
  return result;
}

document.write(power(5, 2));
//returns 25
```

But this won't because even if you don't indent return, it will be executed in the for loop and return during the first iteration. I ran in this issue when I tried your code snipplet so I think it is your issue :

```js
//Power function
function power(base, exponent){

  var result = 1;
  var count = 0;

  for (; count < exponent; count++, result *= base)   //notice the missing brackets
  return result;
}

document.write(power(5, 2));
//returns 25
```